# EmberJs-How to reject an Ember.RSVP.Promise in qunit Unit TEST?

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

```
var stubMyService=Ember.Object.extend({
        //'authenticator:ooion( OAuth,username, password)
        authenticate(OAuth2,username,password)
         {
           return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(reject){
               Ember.run(null,reject,obj);
           });
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback to RSVP.Promise accepts 2 arguments - resolve, and reject.

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Ember.run(null, reject, obj);
});
```

Or, in ES2017 syntax:

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => Ember.run(null, reject, obj));
```

Comment: works like a charm, but i have this,message = self.get('i18n').t("login_page.inactive_fail"); in my controller which gives me an error (Cannot read property 'class' of undefined) in unit test, it would be extremely kind if you could tell me how to sort this out?